# dynamic generation of html tags is not working and giving fatal error for $this keyword

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
include("con_gen.php");
?>
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")  or die("failed to connect to server !!");
mysqli_select_db($link,"idcard");
$sql = "SELECT static_name FROM static_values";
      $result = mysqli_query( $sql,$this->link);
      $ch='rdbtn';
        if ($result>0) {
      $cnt=0;

        while( $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
         {    
            $this->html[] ='
              <tr >
                    <td>
                <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="span3 bgcolor">
              <?php echo "<label>'.$fetch["static_name"].'</label>";?>

              <select  id='.$fetch["static_name"].' name='.$fetch["static_name"].' data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker form-control" >

                <?php echo "<option>".$row. "</option>";
                 foreach ( $Data->'.$fetch["static_name"].' as $key =>$item) echo "<option value=".$key.">".$item."</option>"; ?>               
                </select> 
                                                </div>
</div>
              </td>

    </tr>'            ;        
        }


      $this->close();
      $this->close(); 
     return implode( "\r\n", $this->html );

     }


echo "<pre>".$html."</pre>";
?>
```

There are some static_name in the static_values table I am fetching those names and generating a html tag, but its not working for me, How should I do?

Here I'm trying to generate dynamic html tags so its giving error how should I solve this error.
I  tried so many times but its not solving am not getting where I'm going wrong

it is giving me following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\dyn_html.php on line 8

Comment: Create an object of Html class you are using.

Comment: It means, you aren't using any class to point the self class properties.
without a class, use of `$this->` is an for sure error.

Comment: please let me know script where should I include here and how

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are not using class or function here. based on your question here is an answer:

```
<?php
include("con_gen.php");

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")  or die("failed to connect to server !!");
mysqli_select_db($link,"idcard");

$sql = "SELECT static_name FROM static_values";
$result = mysqli_query( $link,$sql);
$ch='rdbtn';
$html = array();
if ($result>0) {
    $cnt=0;

    while( $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {    
      $html[] ='
        <tr >
              <td>
          <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="span3 bgcolor">
        <?php echo "<label>'.$fetch["static_name"].'</label>";?>

        <select  id='.$fetch["static_name"].' name='.$fetch["static_name"].' data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker form-control" >

          <?php echo "<option>".$row. "</option>";
           foreach ( $Data->'.$fetch["static_name"].' as $key =>$item) echo "<option value=".$key.">".$item."</option>"; ?>               
          </select> 
                                          </div>
      </div>
        </td>

      </tr>';        
    }
}


echo "<pre>".implode( "\r\n", $html )."</pre>";
?>
```

*Note: I did some changes in your code*

Comment: k i'll see and thnx fr ur time

Comment: @Ginani it is not working properly giving notice like this    Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\dyn_html2.php on line 11

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

`$result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql);`

as first parameter is link to database and second is query.

Read here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I have done that change before only but also its giving that notice

Comment: Are you still using `$this` ?

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below code

```
$data = array();
while( $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) { 
        $html ='
          <tr>
             <td>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                   <div class="span3 bgcolor">
                      <label>'.$fetch["static_name"].'</label>
                      <select  id='.$fetch["static_name"].' name='.$fetch["static_name"].' data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker form-control" >

                         <option>'.$row. '</option>';
                         foreach ( $Data->'.$fetch["static_name"].' as $key =>$item) {
                             $html .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$item.'</option>';          
                         }    
                         $html .= '</select> 
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </td>
            </tr>';
          $data[] = $html;
       }
       mysqli_close($link);
       return implode( "\r\n", $data);
```

I am not sure about the array that you used in your foreach loop. Just try this code with correct array. You have also few issues in your html generation which I corrected here.

Comment: Please feel free to add your comments for down voting whoever down voting. It will be helpful for me to avoid the same mistake in my future answers.